# need help with raw distance function

Tags: optimization

I need help with the following function:

$$ \rho(x,\theta)=\min_{\lambda\in [0,\infty]} d(x ,x+\lambda[\cos \theta, \sin \theta]^T),$$
such that $$ x+\lambda[\cos \theta,\sin \theta]^T\in \bigcup_i \mathcal{W}\mathcal{O}_i$$

1. how to write the 'min' part?
2. what does $\lambda [\cos \theta, \sin \theta ]^T$ mean?
3. my question is not showing up as MathJax symbol.  how can I do that?

Comment: Taking last things first, if you put a dollar sign at each end, you'll get $\lambda [\cos \theta, \sin \theta ]^T$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will be better able to help you if you provide context and definitions for $\mathcal{W}\mathcal{O}_i$, as well as details about what you've tried so far.

Comment: With regards to question #2, it seems that $x$ is meant to be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as is $[\cos \theta, \sin \theta]^T=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} \cos \theta\\ \sin \theta \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: thank you for the hearty welcome.  vadim123, $\mathcal{W}\mathcal{O}_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ obstable.